# C++: String Functions without <cstring>

Tags: c++, string, header-files

I started learning  strings and string functions (from a book) , I learned functions like `strcpy` and  `strcat` and `strncat`..etc

So I started to practice using them in simple programs to get a sense of what they do.

Then I was surprised later that in the book it tells me that i have to use `#include <cstring>` in order to use all these string functions.

I have tried using string functions more than once without  including `<cstring>` so why?

The only header file i included was `<iostream>` and yet i was able to use string functions.

Please someone explain to me why the string functions worked without `<cstring>` and do I need to include it to use string functions, and if no what are the uses of `<cstring>`;

Comment: What compiler are you using? Also, you'd be better off studying `std::string` and related classes. Manipulating `char*`s isn't something you should do very often in C++.

Comment: Im using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you absolutely need to consider switching to `std::string`. Manual memory allocation, while being an interesting and sometimes challenging task, should not be a part of your everyday job.

Having said that, probably the `<cstring>` was #included by some other header you are using in your project. However it's better not to depend on the other headers including `<cstring>` (no one guarantees that they will do always and for every compiler), and include it where appropriate.

Comment: Also my program is a simple program that makes 2 strings and copies one to the other then ouputs. Nothing fancy

Comment: @Mohamed: std::string is really the proper C++ way of string manipulation

Comment: @Mohamed: and I can bet with std::string your program will be even shorter and clearer: `std::string s1 = "some string"; std::string s2 = s1; std::cout << s2 << std::endl;` or if you are `using namespace std;`, just `string s1 = "some string"; string s2 = s1; cout << s2 << endl;`.

Comment: @MohamedAhmedNabil: Learning those is fine, but you should be aware that these C-remnants wouldn't be used in productive C++.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to include `<cstring>` because it is included by `iostream`.

However note that the function you are talking about (`strcpy`, `strcat`, `strncat`) are C function taking `char *` and have their C++ equivalents working with the more convenient `std::string`.

`strcpy`: `std::string::operator=`

```
std::string str2;
std::string str1 = str2; // copy str2 in str1
```

`strcat`: `std::string::operator+=`

```
str1 += str2; // concat str2 to str1
```

`strncat`:

```
str1 += str2.substr(0,n); // concat the first n characters of str2 to str1
```

Answer (score 4):

That would simply mean that `<cstring>` was included by `<iostream>`. When you included `<iostream>` you also implicitly included `<cstring>` through it.

Note that it is not generally guaranteed that `<cstring>` is included by `<iostream>`. You just got lucky that your specific implementation happened to have that inclusion. In a different implementation that might not be the case.

Answer (score 2):

To all likelihood, your c++ standard library version implements some features of iostream with c standard library functions which are located in cstring. Thus, when you include the iostream header file, this will have an `#include` directive that gives you cstring.